# Performance and profiling of OpenMP C++ code in VS107

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, openmp

I have a performance critical piece of C++ code running in Visual Studio 2017 that I've been profiling to look for potential bottlenecks.  The profiler at a high level shows about 80% CPU usage across my eight cores executing this code.  Having loaded in all the kernel symbols, the profiler shows that the busiest function is NTYieldExecution at 52% usage. 
[image: NTYieldExecution]  My guess is that this 52% is not correct, possibly 52% of one thread, but even then I'd be keen to know what's going on under the hood.  I also have my own thread pool code which lead to 100% CPU usage on other code, so I'm wondering whether to move this code to an alternative multi-threading model.  OpenMP is very convenient, but is it inefficient in Visual Studio 2017?  More importantly, is it possible to isolate and remove any such inefficiencies?

Comment: This call stack looks very strange. It does not seem to contain your code at all. Time spent in openmp runtime or in system libraries.

Comment: @VTT, it doesn't, which is what leads me to suspect that OpenMP on Visual Studio 2017 may be taking a separate thread of its own, or at least significant CPU usage.  That said, the section of call tree which includes my own code is listed as 14.5% usage, which I also suspect is totally incorrect.  I know this because if I run the same code without OMP enabled it is about 5-6 times slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as it turned out was that part of the multi-threaded code in this case was inadvertently writing to a variable outside the scope of the OpenMP section which was in turn leading to the automatic insertion of a lock, as seen in the PartialBarrierN::Block.  I resolved this by changing this to a more local variable which resulted in a significant speed up and 100% CPU usage.